# Nest templates inside of templates in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if it is possible to nest templates inside of templates in Laravel 4.  I would like to have a master wrapper template that would include things like the doctype, header and footer and then be able to load in templates into the master templates body section.

This would give me the flexibility of having a nested template for my application pages without having to duplicate code while giving me the ability to use the master template for non-application pages.

Can someone please provide an example as to how this would be done using blades templating engine? Is it possible to pass in a value from the router and then have that value be pushed down to your nested template?

EDIT:

Here is my code for index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
   Some page
@endsection

@section('content')
  @include('layouts.app')
@endsection
```

Comment: yes you can nest child view in parent view, you should have read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views)

Comment: I did read the documentation and this unfortunately does not answer my question.

Comment: you are talking about sub views, and how it didn't solve your problem

Comment: I'm trying to go three layers deep.  From what I am gathering from the documentation it only shows a view with nesting in 1 other view. How do you go multiple layers deep with using blades?  The example in the documentation shows using the controller or the route.

Comment: with blade you can do `@include('view_name')`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working?  I've posted my code in above. Can you give me some guidelines on the logic?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for multiple level nesting

```
//index.blade.php
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
@parent
:: new title
@stop

@section('content')
<p>some static contents here</p>
@stop

//app.blade.php
@section('content')
@parent
<p>Add here what ever you want to add</p>
@stop

now either from your Route or Controller you can nest the index and app, ex-
return View::make('index')->nest('content','layouts.app');
```

And in case you want to pass data to child view you can do this by passing the data as third parameter to `nest()`

```
return View::make('index')->nest('content','layouts.app',$data);
```

Comment: The nest helper is no longer referenced in the recent Laravel documentation. Is it still working as you suggest in your answer here?

Comment: This answer was for Laravel 4. I'm not sure whether it will work for 5 or not.